# Prime and Maximal Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have proved that $<x>$ is a prime but not maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$[x].

I am asked to prove I is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$[x]. $\\$
I = {$f$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$[x] : the constant term of $f$ is even}

Would this be a sufficient proof?

Since $<x>$ is prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$[x]$,$ 2$\notin$$<x>$, then I $\varsubsetneq$ $<x>$, thus I = $\mathbb{Z}$[x].

Comment: You can show that $I=\langle 2, x\rangle$, and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, which is a field, thus $I$ is maximal.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Frank and Kevin, It is great to have my curiosities assisted with great facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $I\subseteq J\subset \mathbb Z[x]$ then $\exists g\in J$ such that $g$ does not belong to $I$  then the constant term of $g$ must be odd .

Suppose $g=(2k+1)+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n\in J$ then $h(x)=2k+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n \in I\subseteq J$

Since $J$ is an ideal $g-h\in J$ thus $1\in J$ thus $J=\mathbb Z[x]$

Answer (score 2):

No, that's wrong in three ways. It's not true that $I\subset \langle x\rangle$, since $I$ contains $2$. Perhaps you meant to say $I\supsetneq \langle x\rangle$, which is true. But this doesn't show $I=\mathbb{Z}[x]$-$I$ is explicitly defined not to equal $\mathbb{Z}[x]$! Furthermore, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is generally not considered a maximal ideal in itself: you are to show that $I$ is a proper maximal ideal. There's no need to say anything about $\langle x\rangle$ here. Instead, just show the quotient ring is a field.

Answer (score 0):

By straight forward verification you can conclude that $I=\langle 2,x\rangle$, and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is a field. Thus $I$ is maximal.